# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value

Tags: java, junit, spring-security, jackson

```
@NotNull
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(value = {@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleGrantedAuthority.class)})
private List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList;
```

Above is my attribute which is a Spring Security interface for setting/authorizing users. In my test, I use the statement below to serialize to JSON as it'll be a an array or list within the JSON request body injected using camel content enricher.

```
String jsonObject =  mapper.writeValueAsString(accountDetails);
```

I get this error because of that above line:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator._reportError(JsonGenerator.java:1897)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.JsonGeneratorImpl.writeStringField(JsonGeneratorImpl.java:202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsExternalTypeSerializer._writeObjectSuffix(AsExternalTypeSerializer.java:163)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsExternalTypeSerializer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(AsExternalTypeSerializer.java:88)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:584)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3681)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3057)
    at com.sammy.controller.HomeControllerTest.checkCreateUser(HomeControllerTest.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @manoj & Mohammad Hasan, it's been two years since and moved on from it since so, I honestly don't remember. I'll try to reproduce the issue to solve it and let you guys know. Have you tried the answers below and they didn't also work for you?

Answer (score 18):

If you've found this page because you're trying to Serialize an object in Spring's JsonSerializer using the JsonGenerator.write(String/Number)Field function and see the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value` error even though you've supplied a value:

Make sure that before you call writeField you've called `JsonGenerator.writeStartObject();`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleGrantedAuthority.class)
        }
)
```

to this,

```
@JsonSubTypes({
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleGrantedAuthority.class, name = "ROLE_ADMIN"),
})
```

Here name parameter of the JsonSubTypes should be the name you used in the JSON object to identify that sub class.

Comment: `UserAccountDetails(..., authorityList=[ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER])` is how the POJO prints it out. And, this is how I load it in: `List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(); authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));` so not sure which name to use as it still throws the same error when I use the authorities name of the list. Also, the Json is supposed to just show an authorityList array object.

Comment: @Sammy65 your comment is not clear to me. Then you can use name = "ROLE_ADMIN". Please see the edited answer.

Comment: @Sammy65 And can you provide more piece of code? When do you get the error? Serializing or deserializing?

Comment: It's when I try to serialize the object using those annotations. When I don't, I get a different error which I've asked a question about also from this link: [ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294830/org-springframework-http-converter-httpmessagenotreadableexception)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize `List< GrantedAuthority>`, you can try to customize a serializer and then register the serializer directly on the class

#### Serializer

```java
public class AuthoritySerializer extends JsonSerializer<SysUser> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(SysUser sysUser, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {      
       List<String> authorities = sysUser.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("id", sysUser.getId());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("username", sysUser.getUsername());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("password", sysUser.getPassword());
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("authorities");
        jsonGenerator.writeArray(authorities.toArray(new String[0]), 0, authorities.size());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
       
    }
}
```